# Bug in modifying and deleting a node in a list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a problem with doubly linked lists.
I have to make a little program that allows me to create a spotify playlist, the actions I need to do are: insert (title, genre, duration), view (entire list), search, edit (title, genre, duration), delete (node).
I have successfully implemented insert, view and search but have problems with editing and deleting.
As for editing, nodes are often lost, I can't understand why.
As for the elimination, on the other hand, all the nodes prior to the one eliminated are always lost.
I have checked and double-checked the code but I can't find any errors, could you help me?
here are the functions:

```
void modifySong(PlayList *pl, Song *s){
    int scelta=0;
    Song *temp;
    temp=(Song *)malloc(sizeof(Song));
    if(s==NULL || temp==NULL){
        printf("Errore!");
        return;
    }
    printSong(s);
    *temp=*s; //copio la canzone
    deleteSong(pl,s);
    while (scelta==0){
        printf("modify?\n 1 name\n"
               "2 genre\n 3 duration\n");
        scanf("%d",&scelta);
        getchar();
        if(scelta == 1){
            printf("\nnew title  : ");
            scanf("%[^\n]s", temp->title);
        }

        if(scelta == 2){
            printf("\nnew genre : ");
            scanf("%[^\n]s", temp->genre);
        }

        if(scelta == 3){
            printf("\nnew duration : ");
            scanf("%f", &temp->length);
        }

    }
    insertSong(pl,temp);


}

void deleteSong(PlayList *pl,Song *s){
    Song* aux= NULL;

    if(s == NULL){  
        printf("\nErrore!\n");
        return;
    }
    aux = s;    //salvataggio in aux del nodo t
    if(aux->prev == NULL && aux->next == NULL){
        pl->top = NULL; //Se il nodo è l'unico nodo della lista, si mette a null la playlist
    }
    else{
        if(aux->next == NULL){
            aux->prev->next= NULL; //Se e' l'ultimo elemento della lista, si mette a null il next del prev del nodo da cancellare
        }
        else
        if(aux->prev == NULL){
            //se il nodo risulta come testa della lista si mette come nuova testa il suo nodo successivo
            //e si setta a null il suo prev
            pl->top = aux->next;
            aux->next->prev = NULL;
        }
        else{
            //se si trova tra due nodi, si collegano questi due nodi
            aux->next->prev = aux->prev;
            aux->prev->next = aux->next;
        }
    }

    free(aux); //Free del nodo
}
```

The whole code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/SRQDgm9A

Comment: Does "I have checked the code" include running it in a debugger with stepping through the relevant functions and watching the variables carefully?

Comment: The code you show is incomplete and the linked code is rather large. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. remove as much as possible from your code as long as the problem is still there and the code still compiles.

Comment: The function seems working for me here is the main I made https://ideone.com/NEqQgn

Comment: @MohamedAkram As for the change, I realized that elements disappear when I change the name, in fact the printout is always in alphabetical order, if the new name changes the print order then some nodes (may) disappear, it seems totally random